Filestore instances sizing considering daily snapshot and weekly snapshot. Also Snapshot Metrics to monitor free space

We are setting up snapshots in Filestore instance and analysing the effect of creating snapshots on instance size. We are creating daily snapshots and retaining them for 7 days, persisting weekly and monthly snapshots. Our understanding is if we delete the snapshots, any data that is required for restoring deleted snapshots is moved into the next snapshot, increasing its size. Hence, we expect the monthly snapshot to be accumulating the size of previous snapshots.Upon testing, we are finding that there is no change in snapshot size upon deleting the previous snapshot, it always shows the same size as instance size. We are using df -h commands. Can you confirm our understanding or are we looking at an incorrect metrics?

Does snapshot take up additional space? We are looking at snapshot_used_bytes and used_bytes metrics after taking couple of snapshots. Are snapshot_used_bytes and used_bytes combined show the total used space of the instance?  To estimate the right sizing of filestore instances with daily snapshots, what is the right metrics to use free raw capacity percent or free_bytes_percent ?


